# GRUB not appearing after reinstalling Ubuntu in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, reinstall

I had 17.0 Ubuntu installed along with Windows 7 as a dual boot.

Since `apt-get` wasn't installing anything I realized I had to update, so I did a fresh install to 18.04, erasing the previous version.

Everything works fine but now I can't boot back into Windows. GRUB isn't showing up. Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you tried to press Shift on early boot?

Comment: It didn't work.  
I changed boot order on Bios and now grub shows up when holding down shift but windows does not appear as an option.

Comment: Did you also tried 'sudo update-grub' under Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, i tried mounting the Windows disk on nautilus and typing 'sudo os-prober', then 'sudo update-grub' again and now it works, thank you.